# "Unknown label type" with numpy and scikit

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

```
X = np.array(...,dtype=np.float64).astype(np.float)
y = np.array(...,dtype=np.float64).astype(np.float)

print(X)
[[-0.5  0. ]
 [ 0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0. ]
 [ 0.  -3.5]
 [-3.5 -3.5]
 [-3.5 -2. ]
 [-2.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0. ]
 [ 0.  -3. ]]
print(y)
[-3.5 -3.5 -3.5 -3.5 -3.5 -2.  -3.  -3.  -3.   1. ]
(10, 2)
(10,)


from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

No matter what I do I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/wave-pool.py", line 174, in <module>
    clf.fit(X, y)
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 192, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 355, in _partial_fit
    if _check_partial_fit_first_call(self, classes):
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 320, in _check_partial_fit_first_call
    clf.classes_ = unique_labels(classes)
  File "/home/ben/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 96, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([-3.5, -3. , -2. ,  1. ]),)
```

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like using floats as 'labels'.  Integers work.  You may need to dig into the `sklearn` docs to learn what constitutes valid learning data.

Comment: Classifier != regressor.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah that makes sense. Converting to strings for equality would be more appropriate for classes

Comment: As @MatthieuBrucher said, `GaussianNB` is a classifier. It needs discrete values as classes, but passing floats in there tricks it into thinking that `y` is real-valued. Hence the error.

Comment: The Y values are not continuous data but discrete classes represented as floats. I imagine scikit rejects floats to avoid errors or because equality test could break.